# Ninject NHibernate on plugin oriented architecture

Tags: nhibernate, ninject

According COMPOSITION ROOT pattern, I must to construct all dependencies graph as close as possible to the application's entry point.

My architecture is plugin oriented. So, if someone wants to extend my base system he can.

For example, in my base system I have this structure:

1. View Layer
2. Services Layer
3. Data Access Layer
4. Model Layer

In DAL, I expose some classes like:

1. IRepository
2. NHibernateRepository
3. ProductRepository

So, I'd like if a plugin wants to extend my base Product class to ExtendedProduct, and then create ExtendedProductRepository that inherits from NHibernateRepository.

The question is:
How can instantiate from my base system an instance of NHibernateRepository using NInject?

So, I know the first thing to do is to construct the graph dependencies:

```
using (var kernel = new StandardKernel())
{
    kernel.Bind(b => b.FromAssembliesMatching("*")
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom<IRepository>()
    .BindAllInterfaces());
}
```

However, I'm figuring out that when I execute something like:

```
kernel.GetAll<IRepository>()
```

It's going to return me a ProductRepository instance, and another ProductExtendedRepository under two IRepository objects.

So, how I can save a ProductExtended object from my base system...?
Another question, would be, how could I inject a object instance in my plugins, or, how can plugins autoinject some instance of base system assembly?

Thanks for all.
I'll appreciate a lot some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this pattern for my NHibernate based projects:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
    T Get(int id);
    void Save(T item);
    void Delete(T item);
}

public class NHibernateRepository<ModelType> : IRepository<ModelType>
    where ModelType : class
{
     // implementation
}
```

then...

```
public interface IProductRepository : IRepository<Product> 
{
    // product specific data access methods
}

public class ProductRepository : NHibernateRepository<Product>, IProductRepository
{
    // implementation 
}
```

... and in Ninject Module:

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(NHibernateRepository<>));
Bind<IProductRepository>().To<ProductRepository>();
```

then you can either request the base functionality like:

```
public Constructor(IRepository<Product> repo) { ... }
```

or specific product repository functionality:

```
public Constructor(IProductRepository repo) { ... }
```

your plugins can either get the base functionality and won't have to register anything:

```
public PluginConstructor(IRepository<ProductExtended> repo { ... }
```

or create their own repositories and register them in a Ninject module.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dave.

It's perfect. I'll try it.

However, how could I save or get or update (whichever IRepository methods)... an ExtendedProduct instance from my base system?

Think the follow out:

```
public interface BasePlugin<T> {...}
```

In another assembly:

```
public class PluginExtendedProduct : BasePlugin<ExtendedProduct>
{
    public PluginExtendedProduct (IRepository<ExtendedProduct> repo { ... }
}
```

My headache is how to create an instance of  (so, ExtendedProduct) in my base system in order to call methods PluginExtendedProduct that uses an IRepository.

I don't know if I'm explaining myself well...

Thanks for all.

Comment: that's exactly how you do it. `IRepository<ExtendedProduct>` will get injected without any additional bindings because `IRepository<>` has already been bound.

Comment: FYI, you would normally add questions as a comment to the answer instead of posting another answer.